# How do you solve a homogeneous ODE using Laplace Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Suppose I want to solve $$y'' - 4y = 0$$ all I.C. zero

Taking the laplace transform I get $$(s^2 -4)Y(s) = 0$$

So y(t) can be anything.

Why am I running into this problem and how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no forcing and zero initial conditions, this is to be expected. Let's solve the problem in another manner.
$$m^2-4=0\Rightarrow m=\pm 2$$
So 
$$
y(t)=Ae^{2t}+Be^{-2t}
$$
Now you say zero IC so
\begin{alignat}{2}
y(0)&=A+B&&={}0\\
y'(0)&=A-B&&={}0
\end{alignat}
Thus, $A = \pm B$ so $A=B=0$ and $y(t) = 0$.

From your Laplace transform, you have 
$$
Y(s) = \frac{0}{s^2-4} = 0\Rightarrow y(t) = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

The laplace transform of $y''-4y$ is $s^2 Y-4Y-sy(0)-y'(0)$.
Thus you should have gotten
$$
Y(s) = \frac{y'(0) + sy(0)}{s^2-4}
$$
which you can then take the inverse laplace transform of.

Comment: The main problem here is that if I assume $y(t) = e^{\lambda t}$, and plug in my assumed solution into the differential equation system (so called method of characteristic equation). I will be able to solve this without invoking any notion of an initial condition i.e. $y(t) = A e^{+2 t} + B e^{-2 t}$. Why is it that in this case the initial condition is so crucial?

Comment: The laplace transform is defined as $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y(t)dt$. This is why $y(0)$ shows up: because the integral starts from $0$. It is simply a fact that the laplace transform for $y'$ involves $y(0)$ (and for $y''$ involves $y'(0)$). This is no different than the method of characteristic equations. Indeed, with that method, you end up with two mysterious constants $C_1,C_2$. What are these constant? They are actually functions of $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$.